# How do you return jsx markup in adapter?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, amcharts4

I have the following code:

```
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("html", (text, target, key) => {
  return `
    <div class="category-label">
      <h3 class="category-label__title">{login}</h3>
      {name} 
    </div>
  `;    
});
```

How do I return a JSX element in a adapter? I need to do something like that:

```
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("html", (text, target, key) => {
  return `
    <div class="category-label">
      <Link to="https:\\bla-bla">Текст</Link>
    </div>
  `;    
});
```

I've read the documentation, I couldn't find anything on the subject. I've looked about adapters, but it always returns either "html" or "text"

Answer (score 1):

amcharts doesn'r support JSX

1. You can return html element with ID and when bootstrap your component into such element (worse performance)
2. You can use `renderToStaticMarkup` from https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html to generate html from jsx. (more bundle size)

Comment: Thank you! I like the option with renderToStaticMarkup. But is it appropriate to use this method not on the server?